# Shadow method of solving differential equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mathematical-physics, mathematics

While reading this answer by Rishab Navneet [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/595835/236734), it is shown how we can visualize the harmonic oscillator as the shadow of a body moving in a circle onto a line. How was it found that the plane curve is a circle? More generally, is there a way to go from differential equations to see the plane curve whose projection onto an axis is associated with the solution of it?

For example, consider the simple pendulum, the differential equation modeling is given as:

$$ \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = \frac{-g}{L} \sin \theta$$

I want to ask if there is any general way to find a plane curve such that when we project the point on the curve onto the $\theta$ axis, we see how the angle of pendulum $\theta$ is evolving with time (like a dot moving on the axis).

It's easy to find that for the first-order Taylor approximation it is a circle, but what about higher-order Taylor approximations for the motion, how do we find for those? That is considered a truncated Taylor expansion till the nth term of sine series:

$$P_n (\theta)= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{ \theta^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} (-1)^k$$

Now, how do I find a plane curve whose projection onto the $\theta$ axis shows $\theta$ evolves with time for the below differential equation given some 'n'?

$$ \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = - \frac{g}{L} P_n $$

Comment: How did you get taylor expansion for sin$\theta$ or cos

Comment: Please don't provide me a link to the proof. I know just want to ask you

Comment: and also did you solve this differential equation to get displacement as a function of time?$$ \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = \frac{-g}{L} \sin \theta$$

Comment: Never said that I did solve it without approximation, I said I used the taylor approximation and did it. This may not be what you are looking for but I had written a whole blog post about deriving the taylor series for sin a few months back :-) [See here](https://brianbabu890.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123)

Answer (score 0):

We have backtraced the curve for which SHM can be represented and if you solve the given differential equation
$$ \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = \frac{-g}{L} \sin \theta$$
you will get a function and you can backtrace if possible.
after finding the function of SHM we have related it with the motion on circle
You can also do so but you know it will become very complex.

Comment: Well that is 'circular reasoning' no joke intended. Using the circle method of solving the equation involves knowing that it is a circle only, so you've gone full circle in trying to solve it.

Comment: @Buraian sorry but can you please say it a bit simpler, I am having difficulty in understanding your comment.

Comment: Using the shadow method, we solve the differential equation.

To figure out that it is a circle which shadows the equation, we need the solution of differential equation already/ the function.

Comment: Those two things loop onto each other and you are going full circle in trying to explain it. [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116607/discussion-between-buraian-and-pranav-aggarwal).